# Existence of integration on specific subintervals of $[0,1]$ implies function is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that
>
> (1) $f$ is bounded.
>
> (2) $f$ is integrable on  $[\delta,1]$ for every $0<\delta<1$.
>
> True or false: $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$.

I was unable to get counterexample showing $f$ need not be integrable; but on the other hand, $f$ is bounded on whole domain; so I lead to confusion about the answer. I was feeling that it could be definition of one type of improper integration, where *we declare* $f$ is integrable under conditions (1) and (2), but I didn't justify why limit of $\int_{\delta}^1 f$ exists as $\delta\rightarrow 0$.

Any hint for the question?

Comment: By integrable do you mean Riemann integrable?

Comment: Yes Riemann integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $\overline{\int_a^b} f(x)\,dx$ and $\underline{\int_a^b} f(x)\,dx$ for the upper and lower Riemann integrals, respectively.  Since $f$ is bounded, there is some $M$ such that $|f|\leq M$ and we know that both the upper and lower Riemann integrals are finite.  Now, for any $0 < \delta < 1,$
$$\begin{align*}
\left|\overline{\int_0^1} f(x)\,dx - \underline{\int_0^1}f(x)\,dx\right| &= \left|\left(\overline{\int_0^\delta}f(x)\,dx + \overline{\int_\delta^1}f(x)\,dx\right) - \left(\underline{\int_0^\delta}f(x)\,dx + \underline{\int_\delta^1}f(x)\,dx\right)\right| \\
&= \left|\left(\overline{\int_0^\delta}f(x)\,dx + \int_\delta^1 f(x)\,dx\right) - \left(\underline{\int_0^\delta}f(x)\,dx + \int_\delta^1 f(x)\,dx\right)\right| \\
&= \left|\overline{\int_0^\delta}f(x)\,dx - \underline{\int_0^\delta}f(x)\,dx\right| \\
&\leq \left(\overline{\int_0^\delta}|f(x)|\,dx + \underline{\int_0^\delta }|f(x)|\,dx\right) \\
&\leq 2M\delta \to 0 \qquad \text{ as } \delta \to 0^+
\end{align*}$$

From here, we conclude $\displaystyle \overline{\int_0^1}f(x)\,dx = \underline{\int_0^1 }f(x)\,dx,$ so $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[0,1].$

Comment: Upper Riemann integral is infimum of upper Riemann sums, infimum taken over partitions?

Comment: @Beginner Correct.

Answer (score 1):

True, $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1].$

Suppose $|f|\le M;$ we can assume $M>0.$

Let $\epsilon>0.$ Choose $\delta <\epsilon/(4M).$ Because $f$ is integrable on $[\delta,1],$ there exists a partition $P$ of $[\delta,1]$ such that $U(P,f)-L(P,f)<\epsilon/2.$

Define $P^*= \{0\} \cup P.$ Then $P^*$ is a partition of $[0,1],$ and we have

$$U(P^*,f)-L(P^*,f)=(\sup_{[0,\delta]}f)\cdot\delta - (\inf_{[0,\delta]}f)\cdot\delta+ U(P,f)-L(P,f)$$ $$< 2M\delta + \epsilon/2<\epsilon.$$

This proves $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1].$

Answer (score 0):

$|\int_s^{t} f(x)dx | \leq M(t-s) \to 0$ as $0<s<t \to 0$ where $M$ is a bound for $|f|$. This implies that $\lim \int_{\delta} ^{1} f(x)dx$ exist and is finite. Hence the improper integral exists.

Comment: So, such integrations are improper? Can you give one example of such kind, where we evaluate $\int_0^1 f$ by evaluating $\int_{\delta}^1 f$ and taking limit as $\delta\rightarrow 0$, **but** it is not possible directly to evaluate the integration $\int_0^1 f$.

Comment: Actually any such function is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$. Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability gives this result. But the problem is there is no obvious elementary proof of this so we have to treat this as an improper integral since the hypothesis only says it is integrable on $[\delta, 1)$ for each $\delta >0$.